# Compile error for Angular JS with js/ajax.js and index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, node.js

When I compile my code there is an error with angular.

The code is written from a book, and it works when I load the page using the code at the end of the question.

There seems to be two issues from what I have read. Where do I put the $scope and $compile code?

Mostly, the question is how do I load a document ready trigger with a button for angular JS?

Or should I always load the angular js and hide the code?

```
<div id="myTabs">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class= "tabs">
            <li ><a href="#a" id="listA">LIST</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#b" id="gridB">GRID</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#b" id="listC">GRID</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top:100px">
        <div id="a">


        </div>
        <div id="b">
            <ul class="gallery-items" id="grid">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="c" >


    <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" />
      {{item.description}}<br>
      Rating: {{item.rating}} stars<br>
      <span ng-repeat="idx in stars" 
            ng-class=
              "{true: 'star', false: 'empty'}[idx <= item.rating]" 
            ng-click="adjustRating(item, idx)">&nbsp;
      </span>      
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ajax.js has a function that calls the #c tab to load

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#listC').click(function(){
    angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.stars = [1,2,3,4,5];
      $scope.items = [100];
      $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'changeView.php',
        data:{action: 'getGrid'},
        success:function(data){
          var data = JSON.parse(data);
          for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            var imageLI = makeImage(data[i]['imageID'], data[i]['name'], data[i]['desc']);
            $scope.items[i] = imageLI;


          }


        }

      });
      console.log($scope.items);

      $scope.adjustRating = function(item, value){
        item.rating = value;
      };  
    }]);
});
$('#listC').trigger('click');

    function makeImage(ID, name, description){

      var image = {
        description: description,
            img: '../uploads/'+name,
          rating: 4
      }


      return image;
```

Comment: and the exact error message is...?

Comment: Error: [$injector:modulerr] angular

Comment: There's more than that. I suggest you use the unminified version of `angular.js` while developing (if you aren't already) as the error messages are better

Comment: I have already tried to start from the code that works without tabs, and document.ready() function.

Comment: Now the angular.js only loads after clicking

Comment: do you have ng-app defined in html ?

Comment: Yes inside the HTML
<html  ng-app="myApp">